# magento admin product edit error Fatal error: Call to a member function

Tags: magento, production-environment

I removed an attribute brand_lago from database with help of a script

```
<?php include 'app/Mage.php'; Mage::app(); $setup = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup', 'catalog_setup');$setup->AddAttribute('catalog_product', 'brand_logo'); echo 'Finished';
```

After removed this attribute when i login in admin and edit product it show me error

Fatal error: Call to a member function setAttribute() on boolean in /home/public_html/domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php on line 366

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Have you remove attribute or add attribute?

Comment: You need to check this link for your requirement. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/69455/call-to-a-member-function-setattribute-on-a-non-object-after-magento-migration

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the above mentioned script to remove attribute ? That script will add the attribute into catalog_product. It has `$setup->AddAttribute('catalog_product', 'brand_logo');`

Can you do one thing, go to your database and search for `brand_lago` in `eav_attribute` table ( put this in attribute_code field and search or use `SELECT * FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code="brand_lago";` ). Delete the entry and try to check the admin catalog product management section again.

One more thing. If you installed any module that use this attribute, then disable that module or remove the line of code from that module which use this attribute.

Comment: Hi , sorry actually by mistake i placed wrong code  here is correct script i used to remove  attribute <?php include 'app/Mage.php'; Mage::app(); $setup = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup', 'catalog_setup');$setup->removeAttribute('catalog_product', 'brand_logo'); echo 'Finished';
then i tried to add attribute back again with same script by changing remove to add attribute but did not worked

Comment: Hello, if you want to add or remove product attribute, use the Magento default attribute management system which under catalog > attributes > manage attribute. After create, assign the attribute to attribute set. If you know the module which associated to this attribute, check the MySQL setup file and you will find the attribute add script. That will give you a better idea about this attribute is used for.

Comment: Thanks Good idea , but i was wanted to do it via mysql or PHP script , but i liked your reply thanks i think its better to add attribute from admin